# Worklight Session being seen on multiple devices

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

Have a simple multipage form in worklight using HTTP adapter. When two users are trying to create accounts at the same time. Which ever user started the process last will see their data on the other users device. It looks like they are sharing the same session.

Does this sound like something anyone has seen before?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about this, but try adding `connectAs="endUser"` to your procedure declaration in the adapter XML file.

Comment: I had tried that but then it barks at me and says the Procedure "blah" will always require authentication when connectAs="endUser". Since there is no authentication required here, there are no authentication procedures connected. But is seems that if I wait about 30 - 40 seconds in-between, then each client will have their own sessions.

Comment: See Anton's reply, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639017/add-dummy-authentication-to-ibm-worklight-to-create-new-sessions